# Why is there no way to unbind an HttpApplication event handler out of IHttpModule initialization scope

Tags: c#, asp.net, binding, ihttpmodule, httpapplication

Let's say we want to execute some action only once or a couple of times after web application has started and during a web request.

```
public class WebApp : HttpApplication
{
    public override void Init()
    {
        base.Init();

        this.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(this.OnFirstBeginRequest);
    }

    private void OnFirstBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do some action and if everything is OK, unbind this handler,
        // because we need it executed only once at the first web request
        this.BeginRequest -= new EventHandler(this.OnFirstBeginRequest);
    }
}
```

The following exception will be thrown:

> Event handlers can only be bound to
>   HttpApplication events during
>   IHttpModule initialization.

Comment: Why you don't use `Global.asax` and `Application_Start` ?

Comment: Just came across a similar question yesterday: [Why can event handlers can only be bound to HttpApplication events during IHttpModule initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2781346/102112).

Comment: Xaqron, why should I? That would complicate that code sample, shifting the subject of my question to a different direction.

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't make sense to use event handlers in an `HttpApplication` instance to execute some code on the first request to your application, because each time a new `HttpApplication` instance is created it's going to rebind those events and the code in the event handlers will run again.

Multiple `HttpApplication` instances are created by the ASP.NET worker process. They are pooled for performance purposes, but there can definitely be more than one instance of the `HttpApplication` servicing requests for your web app.

[Here's a pretty good article on the subject](http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/41/ihttpmodule-gotchas---the-init---method-can-get-called-multiple-times).

Comment: Yep, and exactly for that reason I need to UNBIND an event handler which was registered inside Init() method after it has done it's job. The question remains, why ASP.NET doesn't allow to do it.